# Determine if there was a mySQL error with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

All,
If I run a query like the following:

```
 $qry = "Select wrong_column from table_name";
 $result = mysql_query($qry);
```

If wrong_column doesn't exist then I'll get a mySQL error. In PHP, how can I determine if there was an error from mySQL? If there was an error I'd like it to stop further processing but if there wasn't an error I'd like to get the mySQL results like this:

```
$resultset = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Would doing something like this work?

```
if(!mysql_error()){
    $resultset = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

Any advice on how to do this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I determine if there was an error from mySQL?

To see if an error occured you should test the result of `mysql_query`:

```
$result = mysql_query($qry);
if (!$result) {
    $error = mysql_error();
    // Handle the error.
}
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or **FALSE on error**.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Would I want it to be !$result or leave it as !result?

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_query("SELECT foo FROM bar") or exit(mysql_error());` is your best friend =)